# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable - Loop

Tags: python, python-3.7

esto intendando hacer un for para asignar una señal cada vez, sin embargo me sale el siguiente error y no encuentro el porqué.

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

El fragmento del codigo es el siguiente:

```
def segment_cylce(signal):

    x=[]
    for i in (len(peaks)-1):
       x.append(signal[peaks[i]:peaks[i+1]])
    x = np.array(x)  
    return x
```

No se si alguien me podria ayudar

Comment: Bienvenida Maria Jose a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿De dónde sale y que es `peaks`? Si realmente el error está en este código,  pareciera ser que esta variable es un objeto `int` cuando por el código, parece que esperas un iterable, por ej. una lista

Answer (score 1):

La expresión `len(peaks) - 1` produce un resultado entero, que no es iterable.

Lo que tú quieres es:

```
for i in range(len(peaks) - 1):
```

ya que la función range si es un iterable (produce una lista de valores enteros)